# IntelliJ IDEA - Recently Edited Tabs

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm new to the IntelliJ IDEA.  Is there a way to open or find a recently edited and/or closed files?  I seem to have accidently closed a tab in a large program and I am having trouble relocating it.

Comment: Alt-Shift + (left arrow) ?

Comment: I think he mean tabs or tools? Try view->tools window

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `View` | [**Recently Changed Files**](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/navigating-to-recent.html) (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>).

`View` | `Recent Files` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>) will show the recently closed files.

There is also **Reopen Closed File** action, but it has no default shortcut, you can assign it in the IDE Keymap settings.

> To navigate to a recently edited file
>
> 1. On the main menu, choose View | Recently Changed Files or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>.
> 2. From the Recently Edited Files pop-up window that opens select the desired file.

Comment: The OP mentioned "recently edited and/or closed tabs" so there's also `View > Recent Files` (`CTRL` + `E`) for recently closed (i.e. not necessarily edited) files.

Comment: Thanks to both CrazyCoder and glitch for you're answer and comment, respectively.  This is exactly what I was looking for and now have knowledge of both options at my disposal.